# How do I access this array

Tags: php

Hi I have an array result which is generated by following code:

```
//Get House Sales Date
// Create a stream
$username = "test";
$password = "test";
$remote_url2 = "https://www.streetcheck.co.uk/api/v1/postcode/".$cleanpostcode."/saleprices";
$opts2 = array(  'http'=>array(    'method'=>"GET", 'header' => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password")));
$context2 = stream_context_create($opts2);

//Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$json2 = json_decode(file_get_contents($remote_url2, false, $context2));

//If Valid Results Returned
if($json2->message="ok")
{
    print_r($json2);
```

The results of the query can be seen [here](http://prntscr.com/59okbm).

What I need to be able to do is for each result, to insert values to another table, so far I am looking at something like this:

```
foreach ($json2->result->sales as $item1)
{
    $pricepaid = $json2->result->sales->pricePaidGBP;
    $propertytype = $json2->result->sales->propertyType;
    $holding = $json2->result->sales->holding;
    $nameornumber = $json2->result->sales->nameOrNumber;
    $fulllocation = $json2->result->sales->fullLocation;
    $dateoftransfer = $json2->result->sales->dateOfTransfer;
```

But the results are coming back as null, what am I doing wrong please>

Comment: probably want `$pricepade = $item1->pricePaidGBP`. otherwise why bother looping on "->result->sales" and then utterly ignoring the variable that the loop is producing for you?

Answer (score 1):

Convert to an array -

```
$json2 = json_decode(file_get_contents($remote_url2, false, $context2), true);
```

Then you can retrieve like this for each item -

```
foreach ($json2 as $item)
  {
  $pricepaid = $item['result']['sales']['pricePaidGBP'];
  // ... the rest of the items
```

Comment: it looks like an array within an object

Comment: Post was edited, but it's still an array of arrays here, you have to make a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this:

```
foreach ($json2->result->sales as $item) {
    $pricepaid = $item->pricePaidGBP;
    $propertytype = $item->propertyType;
    $holding = $item->holding;
    $nameornumber = $item->nameOrNumber;
    $fulllocation = $item->fullLocation;
    $dateoftransfer = $item->dateOfTransfer;
    ...
}
```